# Is there a workaround for launching Google Actions for countries where Transactions API is not available

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Recently, one of our Actions was rejected because it allowed the user to book an appointment but did not use Transactions API. So we had a few questions regarding the review process and the policy guidelines for Actions that use Transactions API.

1. Is there a way (by modifying the codebase or contacting the support) using which you can launch your Action for countries where Transactions API is currently unsupported?
2. Can you launch different (with and without Transactions API) versions of a single Action for different countries?
3. If someone is offering services that require enablement of Transactions API, does it limit the location targeting to only include the countries where the API is currently supported?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there a way (by modifying the codebase or contacting the support)
   using which you can launch your Action for countries where
   Transactions API is currently unsupported?

   **If you are knowing where the Transactions API is supported you can select your target county while Giving it for Approval from your action console.**
2. Can you launch different (with and without Transactions API)
   versions of a single Action for different countries?

   **As the invocation name will be chaos You can not upload your action with different critearea with different location.**
   **Action store is same like Play store or App store where you can upgrade your action or app but can't duplicate in same manner.**

   **One-word names are not allowed, unless the name is unique to your brand or trademark within the target country. Instructions to request an exception for individual countries are below. Compound words broken into multiple words will 
   not circumvent this requirement, for example key board counts as one word.**

   **Two-word names are not allowed if one of the words is a definite article (the), indefinite article (a or an), pronoun (like my), or preposition (for, to, or of). For example, your name should not be a bicycle, an espresso, to amuse or for fun.**
3. If someone is offering services that require enablement of
   Transactions API, does it limit the location targeting to only
   include the countries where the API is currently supported?

   **For an alternative solution you can use web payments where you can do some payment and give callback to your server. (i think thats allowed in most countries if you have global payment options available)**

*Actions that enable Transactions aren't currently available on Android (Go edition) devices.*